# Azure AD and Authorization on self Developed Applications

Tags: api, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have read the documentation on Microsoft.com and have only got answers about giving Applications authorization to talk to eachother but not how to implement a permission system on each different application that I have. 
I basically want to know what the best practices are to implement Authorization on my .Net API and Angular Client. 
I would use Azure AD to redirect external and internal users to the Microsoft Sign-In Page, I am missing a fine grained Permission system to authorise users to access different Resources on the API or on the Angular Web Application.
Wo I have to set up a DB for my API with permissions? 
How do I add new users to my DB after registering them to my AD?

Im really confused here, so my questions aren´t really as clear as I wish I could write them.

Comment: Per-user permissions are limited to appRoles, roles that you can give in Azure AD to users. You can also use security groups to achieve a similar thing if you want. But anything finer-grained has to be implemented on the app side.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Do you know how I can synchronize AD Users to my DB? I would maybe store some ID key on my side to be able to identify the user? Do you know of services that already have this functionality.

Comment: Not aware of services like that. You can use one of two claims in the user Id token / access token to identify the user. `oid` or `sub`. The oid is the unique immutable object id in Azure AD. The sub claim is a unique immutable id within your app. So every app gets the same oid, but a different sub for the same user. The oid claim is also used when calling e.g. MS Graph API to identify the user.

Comment: Would you recommend letting external users register via the Azure AD redirect? Do I have to create domains to separate internal from external?

Comment: If you make your app multi-tenant, i.e. allow sign in from any organization, you can identify the organization of the user from the `tid` claim. To allow sign in from guest users in your organization, no modification is needed, as long as your app uses the single-tenant authorization endpoint. If you want to limit which users can access the app in your tenant, you can do that from the Enterprise app's settings in the Enterprise apps tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling comments to a proper answer:

Per-user permissions are limited to appRoles, roles that you can give in Azure AD to users. You can also use security groups to achieve a similar thing if you want. But anything finer-grained has to be implemented on the app side.

For identifying users you can use one of two claims in the user Id token / access token. oid or sub. The oid is the unique immutable object id in Azure AD. The sub claim is a unique immutable id within your app. So every app gets the same oid, but a different sub for the same user. The oid claim is also used when calling e.g. MS Graph API to identify the user.